# QTableView::scrollTo() (finding the right QModelIndex)

Tags: qt, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get PgDown clicks on a QTableView to scroll down a variable number of rows.  I talk to my subclassed QSortFilterProxyModel which talks to the subclassed QAbstractTableModel to figure out what the next row is.  That's all fine and dandy but I believe I'm faced with two caveats:
1: The row number inside the view doesn't do much.  I need a QPoint on the screen to scroll to, and I'm not sure how to derive that from a cell.
2: I can create an index in the QSortFilterProxyModel but this generally causes crashes, as the parent is different... or I'm missing something.

```
    int nextRow = getModel()->nextRow( indexAt( rect().topLeft() ) );
    QModelIndex nextIndex = getModel()->index( nextRow, 0 );

    scrollTo( nextIndex, QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop );
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured this out:
        QModelIndex nextIndex = getModel()->index( nextRow, 0 );

```
    scrollTo( nextIndex, QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop );
```

I was having the QSortFilterProxyModel create and index which was a big no-no. I have issues when I have hidden rows, but should hopefully be able to figure that out.